# How to print the value in third column of a line which comes after a line which, contains a specific string using AWK to a different file?

Tags: string, awk, line, matching

I have an output which contains something like this in the middle.

```
  Stopping criterion = max iterations
  Energy initial, next-to-last, final = 
        -83909.5503696     -86748.8150981     -86748.8512012
```

What I am trying to do is to print out the last value(3rd column) in line after the line which contains the string "Energy" to a different file. and I have to print out these values from 100 different files. currently I have been trying with this line which only looks at a single file.

```
awk -F: '/Energy/ { getline; print $0 }' inputfile > outputfile
```

but this gives output like:

```
       -83909.5503696     -86748.8150981     -86748.8512012
```

Update - With the help of a suggestion below I was able to output the value to a file. but as it reads through different files it overwrites the final output file and prints out value of the final file that it read. What I tried was this,

```
#SBATCH --array=1-100

num=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID..
fold=$(printf '%03d' $num)

cd $main_path/surf_$fold
awk 'f{print $3; f=0} /Energy/{f=1}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: I only need the third value, what I am trying to do is read through 100 different files with similar outputs and from all those 100 different files i want just that perticular value printed one below the other.

Comment: You tried what? Don't put code or input/output or requirements in comments where it can be missed and can't be formatted. [edit] your question to show what you tried that caused the problem you describe so we can best help you. It sounds like you're asking for ahelp with a solution that processes multiple input files so you should show at least 2 or 3 input files in your question along with the expected output given that input. We need you to provide a [mcve] that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against.

Comment: Sorry I was trying put out the code here, but I am having a hard time, i'll just update the question itself

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to awk commands. I updated my question, hope it is clear now what I am doing.

Comment: The quick workaround for your problem is to use `>>` (append) instead of `>` (overwrite) but that's probably the wrong answer and just putting a bandaid on the problem. The better answer (unless you have thousands of input files which you said you don't, you only have 100) is just to call awk once on all files at one time instead of calling it one file at a time.

Comment: The way to implement that, though, depends on things you haven't told us yet (what `num=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID..` really is and what it's supposed to do, why you're creating that `fold` variable, etc.) and haven't shown us yet (a directory tree with your file names in it and multiple input files with 1 expected output file).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!! I got the desired output with >> instead of > .

Comment: Honestly, it's kinda disappointing that you went that route as it works around the real problem rather than fixing the real problem but - glad you're happy with it and at least it will produce the output you want as long as you remember to clear the output file before every run.

Comment: You are right, I'll look for the better method(I am not gonna use the current method I was happy about). I might/not remember to clear out that output everytime I run the script. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be an appropriate job for getline, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline, and idk why you're setting FS to `:` with `-F:` when your fields are space-separated as awk assumes by default.

Here's how to do what I think you're trying to do with 1 call to awk:

```
awk 'f{print $3; f=0} /Energy/{f=1}' "$main_path/surf_"*"/inputfile > outputfile
```